# Store coordinates on save or on calculate them on map view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In ruby on rails what is the general approach for displaying markers of user entered addresses in a google map?

Should I call the geocoding service for every address when the map is loaded or should I call it when the address is saved and then display all coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the answer is to call the geocode on save. Otherwise I'll go over the 2500 call/day limit for google maps geocoding service

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely geocode the address when the user provides you with one, and then save the received latLngs in your database. This way saves the amount of geocoding requests.